# Action required: 7 days left to recover Google Compute Engine resources in billing disabled projects

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I recived this mail from google...

Hello,
Your Google Cloud Platform project(s): 
Google Play Android Developer
has/have been in the billing disabled state for more than 30 days. Since a valid billing account is required for Google Compute Engine, all related Google Compute Engine resources are scheduled to be deleted in as soon as 7 days.

Please note your Google Cloud Platform project(s) will not be deleted, and other services that do not depend on Google Compute Engine resources will not be affected.

If you take no action within 7 days, you will be unable to recover any resources under Google Compute Engine in this project. If disabling billing was unintentional, please follow the online instructions a and re-enable billing for this project within 7 days to avoid the resource deletion.

If you have any questions, please visit the Project Billing Help page or Contact Support from the links below.

What is the meaning of this?
Does my developer account deleted after 7 days?
Does i have to pay 25$ registration fee again?
I never used cloud services then wht google send me this mail.
Please help ...

Answer (score 4):

This email was sent out my mistake to some recipients. If you're not using Google Compute Engine then you can ignore the email:

> The email quoted below was sent to some Google Cloud Platform customers in error.
>   If you do not use Google Compute Engine, you can safely ignore that message. We apologize for any confusion this has caused. We received feedback from many customers who do not use the Google Compute Engine service (for example, they only use Google App Engine). Your Google App Engine apps will continue to operate normally, and you do not need to take any action at this time.
>   Thanks,
>   The Google Compute Engine Team